# How do I log EntityValidation errors using ELMAH MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5, elmah, elmah.mvc

I've been writing an application using MVC4 and EF5.x, and using ELMAH for logging exceptions for review. We recently released the application, and as expected the ELMAH log filled up with several dozen exceptions. Great (and not)! The problem is that one of those exceptions is

```
System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException
Validation failed for one or more entities. 
See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.
```

Of course, there's no way to see the EntityValidationErrors property for more details and the stack trace wraps up to my SubmitChanges()

I know ELMAH has the capability of allowing us to raise our own exceptions, and in some way customize what gets logged and how. Unfortunately, I'm still very new to ELMAH and MVC and a Google search didn't turn up anything relevant. I did find [a blog article](http://blog.ivanovtech.com/) on logging EntityValidationErrors, and the author specifically mentioned that he would post how to do so in ELMAH but that was posted in September of 2012 and I didn't see anything since then.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Probably the best thing to do in this case would be to wrap your `context.SaveChanges();` call in a `try...catch` block and then log the individual items from the ValidationExceptions. Something like the following should get you started:

```
try
{
    context.SaveChanges();
}
catch (DbEntityValidationException ve)
{
    var error = ve.EntityValidationErrors.First().ValidationErrors.First();
    var msg = String.Format("Validation Error :: {0} - {1}", 
               error.PropertyName, error.ErrorMessage);
    var elmahException = new Exception(msg);

    Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(elmahException);
}
```

Comment: Why not only catch DbEntityValidationException instead of casting?

Comment: Also, you could use LINQ to select all the errors as a list of string and join them rather than selecting the first one.

Comment: A more central solution would be preferred. Such as overriding the function where Elmah catches the errors and checking if it is a `DbValidationError` then further look into it,

Comment: I did this, but instead at my lower level I'm catching the validation exception and wrapping them in a new exception and re-throwing. That way I don't need this at every controller or service level, any exception with validation errors should now have the info.

Answer (score 5):

How about this extension method based on the above..

```
public static void SaveChangesWithBetterValidityException(this DbContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException ve)
        {
            var errors = new List<string>();
            foreach (var e in ve.EntityValidationErrors)
            {
                errors.AddRange(e.ValidationErrors.Select(e2 => string.Join("Validation Error :: ", e2.PropertyName, " : ", e2.ErrorMessage)));
            }
            var error = string.Join("\r\n", errors);
            var betterException = new Exception(error, ve);

            throw betterException;
        }
    }
```

Elmah will then have a much better exception in it's log

Answer (score 3):

I added the following to my `Global.asax.cs` in order to forward all `DbEntityValidationException` exceptions to Elmah across my MVC application:

```
private void ElmahEntityValidationException()
{
    var dbEntityValidationException = Server.GetLastError() as DbEntityValidationException;

    if (dbEntityValidationException != null)
    {
        var errors = new List<string>();
        foreach (var entityError in dbEntityValidationException.EntityValidationErrors)
        {
            errors.AddRange(entityError.ValidationErrors.Select(e2 => string.Join("Validation Error :: ", e2.PropertyName, " : ", e2.ErrorMessage)));
        }
        var error = string.Join("\r\n", errors);
        var betterException = new Exception(error, dbEntityValidationException);

        Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(betterException);
    }
}

protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ElmahEntityValidationException();
}
```

Some of this code was reused from @Paige Cook's and @Original10's posts.

Comment: One cant add this in the filters section under app_start?

Answer (score 1):

Re-throwing as per the code below is not perfect (although I don't mind resetting the call stack here, as Elmah's logged details of the address posted to will show me what lead to the exception) and you will have to work out your own security implications, but this is fairly concise & meets my needs:

```
try
{
    return base.SaveChanges();
}
catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
{
    var de = new DetailedEntityValidationException(e);
    throw de;
}

public class DetailedEntityValidationException : Exception
{
    public DetailedEntityValidationException(DbEntityValidationException ve)
        : base(ve.Message + ":\r\n\t-" + string.Join(new string('-',20) + "\r\n\t-", ve.EntityValidationErrors.Select(ev=>string.Join("\r\n\t-",ev.ValidationErrors.Select(e=>e.ErrorMessage)))))
    {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my implementation for Global Web API solution for Elmah and EF Validation errors:

```
public class ElmahHandleWebApiErrorAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
   public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
   {
       var e = context.Exception;
       // Try parse as entity error (i'm not sure of performance implications here)
       var efValidationError = e as DbEntityValidationException;
      if (efValidationError == null)
       {
           RaiseErrorSignal(e);
       }
       else
       {
           RaiseEntityFrameWorkValidationErrorSignal(efValidationError);
       }
  }

   private static bool RaiseErrorSignal(Exception e)
   {
       var context = HttpContext.Current;
      if (context == null)
           return false;
       var signal = ErrorSignal.FromContext(context);
       if (signal == null)
           return false;
       signal.Raise(e, context);
       return true;
   }

   private static bool RaiseEntityFrameWorkValidationErrorSignal(DbEntityValidationException e)
   {
       var context = HttpContext.Current;
       if (context == null)
           return false;
       var signal = ErrorSignal.FromContext(context);
       if (signal == null)
           return false;

      //Taken from post above
      var errors = new List<string>();
       foreach (var entityError in e.EntityValidationErrors)
       {
           errors.AddRange(entityError.ValidationErrors.Select(e2 => string.Join("Validation Error :: ", e2.PropertyName, " : ", e2.ErrorMessage)));
        }
       var error = string.Join("\r\n", errors);
       var betterException = new Exception(error, e);

       signal.Raise(betterException, context);        
       return true;
   }
}
```

and then I register the attribute in the `WebApiConfig.cs` file under `App_Start`

```
config.Filters.Add(new ElmahHandleWebApiErrorAttribute());
```